# NOT getting success message in JSON IOS

Tags: php, ios, json, afnetworking-3

I am creating simple application. I have a one php script that accept 5 parameters 'firstname','lastname','email','password' and 'key'.

This is my php file code.

```
   <?php
 define("SERVER", 'localhost');
 define("USER", 'root');
 define("PASSWORD", '');
 define("DB", 'test');
 mysql_connect(SERVER,USER,PASSWORD,DB);
 $con = mysql_select_db(DB);
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    $firstname = isset($_POST['firstname']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']) : "";
    $lastname = isset($_POST['lastname']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']) : "";
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']) : "";
    $password = isset($_POST['password']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']) : "";
    $key = isset($_POST['key']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['key']): "";


    if(!empty($firstname) && !empty($lastname) && !empty($email) && !empty($password) && !empty($key) ){

        if ($key == "12345") {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`firstname`,`lastname`, `email`, `password`) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$password');";
            $qur = mysql_query($sql);
            $json = array("status" => 1, "msg" => "Done User added!");
        }
        else{
            $json = array("status" => 0, "msg" =>"key not match");
        }


    }
    else{
        $json = array("status" => 0, "msg" => "Error adding user!");
    }


}else{
    $json = array("status" => 0, "msg" => "Request method not accepted");
}

@mysql_close($conn);

/* Output header */
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

This is screenshot of Advanced Rest Client.
[image: scrren shot of sucessfully inserted data]

All is going good.But when i am trying to post request from ios app using AFNetworking i always getting wrong response.

This is my Objective-C code.

```
    NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [parameters setValue:@"ramu" forKey:@"firstname"];
    [parameters setValue:@"kaka" forKey:@"lastname"];
    [parameters setValue:@"ramu@gmail.com" forKey:@"email"];
    [parameters setValue:@"11111" forKey:@"password"];
    [parameters setValue:@"12345" forKey:@"key"];


    AFHTTPSessionManager *managertwo = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    managertwo.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    [managertwo.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [managertwo POST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:80/Testing/jsonpost.php"] parameters:parameters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"success! %@",responseObject);
        NSLog(@"%@",parameters);

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

And I am Getting Response like this

```
    2016-02-16 12:31:36.783 TestingLocal[1626:110064] success! {
    msg = "Error adding user!";
    status = 0;
}
2016-02-16 12:31:36.783 TestingLocal[1626:110064] {
    email = "ramu@gmail.com";
    firstname = ramu;
    key = 12345;
    lastname = kaka;
    password = 11111;
}
```

I am not understand why this happen.I searched everywhere what is the problem but i am getting nothing. Please help.

Comment: Why is only email under qoutes in your log output? Should not all be strings?

Answer (score 2):

In the server code getting data in $_POST, try using following:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
//replace $_POST with $postdata
```

Actually php://input allows you to read raw POST data.

It is a less memory intensive alternative to $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA and does not need any special php.ini directives.

php://input is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data".

refer http://infopotato.com/blog/index/post

Comment: try printing var_dump($_POST) and var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"))

Comment: @viratpuar - And did you excise the `$_POST` references from your PHP code and instead just `json_decode` the `$postdata`?